# how do I convert a 4-digit integer value to two separate 2-digit values in c++

Tags: c++

What can I do in order to split a 4-digit number so it becomes 2 separate 2-digit numbers?

for example:
let the integer value 1234 become 2 integers 12 and 34 by spiting it.

Comment: If you divide it by 100, what do you get and what's the remainder?

Comment: `/` is for divide and `%` is to find mod. Divide by `100` and then find mod using `100`.

Comment: As what @ShashankSingh said, 1234 / 100 = 12, 1234 % 100 = 34

Comment: Please provide a piece of code to show what you came up with yourself before asking us to do your homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How? Simply do following:

```
int num = 1234;
int a = num % 100;
int b = num / 100;
```

;) have fun coding.